# How to override Init() in the subclass in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, initialization, subclass

I am still a beginner at Swift. I  have a class NonPlayerCharacter as a parent class and a subclass Goblin that inherits from it. I defined health and power inside the NonPlayer class, and I defined weapon inside the Goblin. Then I declare a new variable so I can call class Goblin and change the values of health, power, and weapon but I can't see weapon inside the bracket (I only see health and power). I tried to make an init function, but I got this error " Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer ". I explained my problem more clearly in the comments below inside my code.

I have this class on the Playground

```
class NonPlayerCharacter 
{

  var health: Int
  var power: Int

init() {

    health = 0
    power = 0

}
 init(health: Int , power : Int) {
    self.health = health
    self.power = power

}

func attack () -> String
{
    return "attack from NonPlayer Character"

}    }

var NonPlayerMethod = NonPlayerCharacter(health: 100, power: 90)

 //and this is the SubClass: 

  class Goblin: NonPlayerCharacter
   {
  var weapon : Int = 0

  override func attack() -> String {
    return "attack from Goblin"
 }
 }



 var GoblinMethod = Goblin(health: 40, power: 12)
 GoblinMethod.weapon = 10
 GoblinMethod.attack()

  //I tried to make initialization like this in the SubClass** 


   class Goblin: NonPlayerCharacter
  {
   var weapon : Int = 0

   Init ( weapon: Int )
   {
   self.weapon = weapon 
   }
   }

   // so I can change the values like this :

   var GoblinMethod = Goblin( weapon: 30 , health: 20, power: 50) 

  // I got this error ( Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer )
 //I don't think I need to override Init as the weapon only in the SubClass.
```

Comment: What does `it didn't work` mean?

Comment: When I tried to do it like this,  health and power weren't recognized and the value of weapon didn't change and I got an error @Alexander

Comment: Am I supposed to be able to guess what the error is?

Comment: No of course not. I am sorry here is the error.  Super.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer @Alexander  I will edit my question now.

Comment: Initializing a `Goblin` requires the initialization of a `NonPlayerCharacter`, so you'll need to call `super.init(...)` at some point in your initializer

Comment: Thank you, I was confused because I thought I don't have to call the Super initializer as it is already inherited.  I want also to thank you for pointing out to the mistake I made in the question. I am trying my best to learn how to ask my questions in the right way.  @Alexander

Comment: Super initializers are only inherited if no other initializers are declared in the subclass. If this weren't the case, then it would be possible for you to call the init that sets the health and power, but leaves the weapon undefined. Furthermore, simply inheriting the initializers wouldn't be sufficient, even if it were possible. It would actually need to be called, so as to set the values of health and power

Comment: Good point. Thank you very much for the clarification.  @Alexander

Comment: No problem :) on a side note, you should really clean up the indentation in this code lol

Comment: I hope the formatting is slightly better now :) @Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two ways to handle your case:

1 Create an own initializer for your subclass, call the super initializer and after that initialize the weapon property like this

```
class Goblin: NonPlayerCharacter {
  var weapon : Int = 0

  init(health: Int, power: Int, weapon: Int) {
    super.init(health: health, power: power)
    self.weapon = weapon
  }

  override func attack() -> String {
    return "attack from Goblin"
  }
}
```

Then you are able to create a Goblin like this:

```
var goblin1 = Goblin(health: 30, power: 20, weapon: 50)
```

2 Create a convenience initializer for your subclass to be able to decide if you want to call only the initializer from the parent class (with setting health and power) or the convenience one (with setting health, power and weapon) like this:

```
class Goblin: NonPlayerCharacter {
  var weapon : Int = 0

  convenience init(health: Int, power: Int, weapon: Int) {
    self.init(health: health, power: power)
    self.weapon = weapon
  }

  override func attack() -> String {
    return "attack from Goblin"
  }
}
```

Then you are able to create a Goblin like this:

```
var goblin2 = Goblin(health: 30, power: 20, weapon: 50)
```

or like this:

```
var goblin3 = Goblin(health: 30, power: 20)
```

Further readings [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) and [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119922/swift-tutorial-initialization-part-1)

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, great that I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way. It works but I don't know which one is better between using 'convenience init' and not using.

```
class NonPlayer {
   private var health: Int
   private var power: Int
   init(health: Int, power: Int) {
    self.health = health
    self.power = power
   }

   func attack() {
    print ("비유저에게 공격당했습니다.")
   }
}

class Goblin: NonPlayer {
    private var weaponDamage: Int
    init(health: Int, power: Int, weaponDamage: Int) {
      self.weaponDamage = weaponDamage
      super.init(health: health, power: power)
    }
    override func attack() {
     print("고블린에게 공격당했습니다.")
    }
}

let goblin = Goblin(health: 200, power: 15, weaponDamage: 20)
goblin.attack()
```